# Can not find why POST method not passing some html codes

Tags: php, html

I am using Post form, which works perfectly with any text, but when try to post code like `format=xhtml`, redirect me to 404
I am on this already all night and can not solve it with google`s help.
It is PHP page
Works on the example page
https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphp.php?filename=demo_form_post

Does not work on my server

I am posting

```
content="format=xhtml; url=https://m.1688.com/offer/42866153932.html" />
```

Here is the example code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
    <body>

        <form action="test45.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>

<?php
//include "fetchpage.php";

?>

<?php
  echo "Welcome&nbsp";
  echo $_POST['name'];
  echo "<br> Your e-mail address is:$nbsp";
  echo $_POST['email'];
?>
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: If problem in php that mean your form is correct just cross check your form attributes and input fields name attributes. for more clarification please post your code.

Comment: Can I have the question re-opened, please?

Comment: @TihomirGrozev, change action="test45.php" to action="" in <form> and it should work

Answer (score 1):

> You need to understand php form handling first.

**Please go through this link [php form handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)**

### OR

*Just see the code below..*

---

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

> AND PHP CODE SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS...

---

```
<?php
  echo "Welcome&nbsp";
  echo $_POST['name'];
  echo "<br> Your e-mail address is:&nbsp";
  echo $_POST['email'];
?>
```

*Get it run on: [CLICK HERE...](https://tryphp.w3schools.com/demo/demo_form_get.php)*

**HOPE IT HELPS...**

Comment: Thank you, will try again today, work on the example and same code does not work on my server

Comment: Which server do you use?

Comment: Is it XAMPP or WAMP? I use WAMP, it definitely works on it.

Comment: Or do you use LAMP?

Comment: XAMPP, Work on local host actually, did not on the actual online server. I am looking for some other way to do it. Thinking to make one table row editable, then to filter the tags and store the content in string.

Comment: Ask your online server provider to update the php version.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on 000webhost, my php code doesn't work on it, but it works on my WAMP server

Comment: It is the problem in php version. Earlier php versions were very different. Most of the online server providers have the older versions.

Comment: Try making another file named "Welcome.php" and put the php code in it. And then run the html file. It will work. Be sure that you have both the files in same directory.

Comment: I have edited the code today. (27 Oct 2020) Try now. There was a problem in the previous code.